# Vim - when is the {cmd} command of an autocmd definition executed?

Tags: vim

With the following definitions

```
au CursorMoved * call Speak()
fu! Test()
  normal j
  echom "after j"
endf
fu! Speak()
  echom "CursorMoved"
endf
```

entering `:call Test()` and then checking the messages with `:mess` reveals that the message `after j` precedes the message `CursorMoved`. Why? Shouldn't the event `CursorMoved` happen just at the moment `normal j` is executed (I wouldn't know wether the event happes when `normal j` starts or finishes, but I expect it to happen before the next `echom` command).

Comment: I guess events are triggered asynchronously.

Comment: @leaf no they are not. Vim has been synchronous for a long time, only recently getting async job support. However, i suspect the events dont fire in a function or something like that

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, yes, I suspect the same, like every event happening in a function is stacked somewhere and processed after return, but I hope someone will provide the true answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:help CursorMoved`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorMoved) mentions that

> Not triggered when there is typeahead or when
>   an operator is pending.

This is a bit cryptic. I've inserted a `normal k` after the `normal j` (so that the cursor stays at the same position after leaving the function), and no `CursorMoved` is fired at all!

I guess this means that inside a function, no `CursorMoved` events are fired, and Vim determines after the function ends whether the cursor was effectively moved, and only then a single event is fired. (So a function works like an "operator".) This is in line with how screen updates are suspended while a function is executed (an explicit `:redraw` is needed inside a function). This behavior is good, because often functions need to temporarily move around in the buffer without the user noticing.

In general, you shouldn't rely on such specifics. Hooking into `CursorMoved` is especially critical, because it is fired so often, and therefore has the potential to dramatically slow down Vim.